# How to provide controls for various actions in a single page?

Tags: forms, tables, wireframe

This one is for CMS. The user should be able to add,delete,update and search through a table in a single page.

[image]

**The buttons**

Initially `ADD` is visible, 
If the `edit pencil icon` is clicked only `UPDATE` button is visible, 
If any of the checkboxes are checked only `DELETE SELECTED` button will be visible

**The "message/form for editing" box**

1. It shows the acknowledgements of all the actions (Like *Row(s) Deleted Successfully!*)
2. It shows prepopulated form for updating on the click of the `edit pencil icon`
3. It shows info abt the row on click of the respective `heading` in the table

Now where and how do I fit the search controls without *crowding* the page? The search is based on multiple parameters hence will have multiple inputs. Any ideas please? Any thoughts on the current layout is also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts of the design.

- Use select header as a control for Select all / Clear selection action
- Combine Headline and Link columns
- Re-organize rare/dangerous actions by removing it from each row and applaying them to selection only. It creates longer path to eliminate mistakes and slips
- Use pop-up dialogs for Add, Edit, Advanced search to isolate complex interactions
- Display additional info about selected row close to selection (in-place rather than at fixed position in a top)
- Use disappearing messages, they overlap content but auto-dissapear or closed by user. It's not only more natural but also saves the space.
- Don't hide primary tools, as it requires more cognitive load to discover hidden rules.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much :) ! For pagination say there is a lot of rows hence a lot of pages, What do you think is the minimum no. of links that can be shown like `1 2 3` `10 11 12`, should there be `first page` and `last page` links all the time?

Comment: I think `« ‹-Prev 3 Next-› »` is enough. It's scalable and not scares users with big numbers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Introduce Search Criteria. User can input some or all fields in the criteria and click    **Search** button. The below grid / table will be refreshed every time **Search** button is clicked.
2. Selection of a row in the grid / Table will show the row details in the below **Details** frame.
3. If user wants to add a record, he clicks **New** button. It shows a blank **Details** frame. After user enters the details, he clicks **Add** button
4. If user selects **Delete** option in any row of the table, corresponding row details are displayed in the **Details** frame and user can click **Delete Selected** button to finally delete the record.
5. If user selects **Edit** option in any row of the table, corresponding row details are displayed in the **Details** frame and user can click **Update** button after making changes to existing details.

Hope this is useful ...

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for posting an answer but the page looks a bit crowded now, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid

Comment: you may place the Details frame in a dialog to gain space